# Responsive Design View on Chrome / Safari or IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, safari, resolution

In **Firefox** it is possible for me to go to responsive design view by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> and I can adjust the context area to a size such as `720 * 720`.

How do I do this on **IE**, **Chrome** or **Safari**?

Answer (score 4):

The new rewritten dev tools in IE11 will include a feature to allow you to set the resolution and orientation for the browser, for use with testing responsive layouts.

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

(note, IE11 hasn't been released yet, but it is in preview if you want to try it out)

Comment: as well as IE 9+, see this link http://love2dev.com/#!article/Use-Custom-Resize-to-Make-The-IE9-Mobile-Experience

Comment: Microsoft loves to point to features it will include in their "next version" that other browsers had years ago. I'm pretty sure the OP is looking at current browsers, not unreleased ones.

Answer (score 4):

In Apple's Safari, your best option for diagnosing responsive views is using the following: -

1. Open Safari and click Safari > Preferences > Advanced
2. Enable the "Show Develop Menu in Menu Bar" option and close the preferences dialog
3. There should now be a Develop menu item at the top of your screen
4. Click the Develop menu and the option "Enable Resposnive Design Mode" or use the keyboard shortcut [Command] + [Option] + R.
   `⌥ + ⌘ + R`

Comment: @nivritgupta Excellent, glad I could help (:

Comment: Thanks. How can one accomplish this in mobile Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a javascript tool I use on Safari and Chrome, though I'm not sure how it works in IE; very useful: http://responsive.victorcoulon.fr

Comment: +1 - pretty good but restrictive compared to Firefox version... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in IE. Chrome has something similar when you are in dev tools by clicking on the gear in the right bottom corner as "overrides -> device metrics".

Comment: re IE... there is no such thing **yet**. IE11 will have it. See my answer.

Comment: You can actually do it in IE 9+ http://love2dev.com/#!article/Use-Custom-Resize-to-Make-The-IE9-Mobile-Experience You just need to use the F12 tools like all the other browsers

Comment: @ChrisLove What IE has is a resizer but not the same thing as what Chrome and FF offer with more tools and options.

Comment: @BreakoBreako I believe Safari has the same as Chrome but I'm at a customer site and can't check right now.

Comment: @ChrisLove The link is now https://love2dev.com/blog/use-custom-resize-to-make-the-ie9-mobile-experience/

Comment: thanks, I need to add 301 to the site.
Added to the todo list ;)

Answer (score 2):

The option in my Chrome (32.0.1700.41 beta-m Aura) is "Overrides" -> "Show 'Emulation' view in console drawer". Then click the "Show console" icon found next to the gear icon.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to emulate screen resolutions in Chrome is to dock its Dev Tools to right side (there is the button in right top corner) and then drag its border (and optionally bottom browsers border). Chrome will show current viewport dimensions in its top right corner so you can to, say, 320x480px. It acts very similar to FF Responsive Design View.

Answer (score 0):

#### Chrome

First enable "Emulation" by going to [Settings (Gear Icon)](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) and check **"Show 'Emulation' view in console drawer"**
Now, close the settings panel, and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and you'll get an Emulation tab. You can do a lot of changes there. Changing the screen size, emulating touch, accelerometer, user-agent spoofing, etc.

If you are getting the warning "chrome screen emulation is not available on this page", (probably you're in Linux, where chrome has disabled some things right now), then you'll need to change a [[chrome://flags][chrome://flags] options follow up this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/405858/52971)

---

#### IE11

For IE 11, the F12 Developer Tools have a dedicated tab for changing device metrics, etc.

I don't use Safari, so I can't say about it.